# Building workspace(sleeping)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-appcompat

I have added android-support-v7-appcompat library to my project I got this error:

"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable "

then I right clicked on the android-support-v7-appcompat and unchecked "Dependency"

when I run my project, in progress bar I see

Building workspace(Sleeping)
Ok

then it gets cleaned and then the same message will be giving. 
I can't upload the print screen

any ideas please

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your ide do not generate R.java properly, or your dependency setting may be wrong. Recheck that you've followed the instruction in this page https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

I'm not familiar with eclipse. If you're sure you have the dependency work done, maybe you can try something like "clean" and then "rebuild".

Comment: thanks for quick response 
it means I have to delete my project and re-create it 
right?

Comment: @Jaans it's not the entire project...just files auto-generated, like object files and compile logs. In most case you can clean them by just clicking a button in your ide, but if it not works, you could find error logs (maybe [workspace]/.metadata/.log) and provide more details.